# Calculating speed on an android phone

Tags: android

How to calculate the speed using the phones sensor or GPS. using that i want to calculate the distance and other stuff. I want to find out the speed a person is travelling. even when the phone is in the pocket. how do i do this? Please provide some sample code if possible.

Comment: StackOverflow.com is *not* a free coding service. What have you tried?

Comment: Im trying to make an app which calculates at what speed a person is travelling while he is running or jogging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the example For calculating Speed of your android phone using GPS...

```
LocationManager mlocManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
        LocationListener mlocListener = new MyLocationListener();
mlocManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0,
                mlocListener);



public class MyLocationListener implements LocationListener {

        @Override
        public void onLocationChanged(Location loc) {
            loc.getLatitude();
            loc.getLongitude();

            Geocoder gcd = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext(),
                    Locale.getDefault());
            try {
                mAddresses = gcd.getFromLocation(loc.getLatitude(),
                        loc.getLongitude(), 1);

            } catch (IOException e) {

            }

            String cityName = (mAddresses != null) ? mAddresses.get(0)
                    .getLocality() : TimeZone.getDefault().getID();
            String countryName = (mAddresses != null) ? mAddresses.get(0)
                    .getCountryName() : Locale.getDefault().getDisplayCountry()
                    .toString();


            mCurrentSpeed.setText(loc.getSpeed());
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Disabled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Gps Enabled",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you :) i will definitely try it out :)